# How can I display a webview

Tags: android, webview

I want to display a webview
but it doesn't appear
Can you help me to correct this code please?
I didn't understand if the the error is in the xml code or in the java code

```
    <ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:androido="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardview"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                card_view:cardElevation="20dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:background="@color/lignt_blue"
                        android:paddingLeft="25dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Cordonnées"
                            android:textSize="14sp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:background="@color/navy" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                        android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:paddingTop="20dp"
                        android:paddingBottom="10dp">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Login"
                            android:id="@+id/textLog"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textSize="20sp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:enabled="false"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:id="@+id/editTextlog"/>
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:layout_height="2dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Nom"
                            android:id="@+id/textNom"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:textSize="20sp"/>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:enabled="false"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                            android:id="@+id/editTextId"/>
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:layout_height="2dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Prenom"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:id="@+id/textPrenom"
                            android:textSize="20sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:enabled="false"
                            android:id="@+id/editTextName"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:layout_height="2dp"
                            android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/textEmail"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:text="Email"
                            android:textSize="20sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/editTextSalary"
                            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
                        <View
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_margin="10dp"
                            android:layout_height="2dp"
                            androido:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/textTel"
                            android:textStyle="bold"
                            android:text="Téléphone"
                            android:textSize="20sp"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:clickable="true"
                            android:autoLink="phone"
                            android:id="@+id/editTextTel"
                            android:textColor="@color/black" />


                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

I add my webview with longitude and latitude from the database

java code

```
String latitude=c.getString("latitude");
            String longitude =c.getString("longitude");
            browser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
            browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            browser.loadUrl("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
```

Comment: May be your latitude, longitude are empty strings. check once

Comment: they aren't empty. I already used Log.e("latitude", latitude);
            Log.e("longitude",longitude);. It returns values

Answer (score 0):

Could you past your `MyBrowser` class? 
One small tip - try to change your layout code with some styles. You have tons of TextView's and View's which looks like identically - move the same attributes to styles, and your xml will become shorter and more elegant

Comment: public class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}

Comment: Add some height (e.g. 200dp) of WebView and it will appear.